# Jquery copy paste issue

Tags: jquery

I have multiple selection in HTML5 and I wanted to select one or multiple option then put them into the other selection. I did it with jQuery but the issue is I want to select from the right and copy into an input with a type text.

Here is the code :

```
 {{#if items}}
    <select multiple id="gauche">
    {{#each items}}
        <option value="{{value}}">{{name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
    </select>
            <button id="add" data-actionname="ajouteritems" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
            <button id="delete" data-actionname="enleveritems"class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">< Enlever </button>
{{else}}
    <p> il n'y a pas d'item </p>
{{/if}}
<select multiple id="droite" required >
</select>
<button id="ok" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-actionname="choisir">choisir</button>
```

and the jQuery code to take from the left and paste into the right

```
var ajouteritems = function(bouton){
    // ici this doit être ma classe formulaire1 (google javascript call)
    var t = this;

    //google jquery selector
    var lesoptions = $('#gauche').find(":selected");
    $('#droite').append(lesoptions);

};
var enleveritems = function(bouton){
    var lesoptions = $('#droite').find(":selected");
    $('#gauche').append(lesoptions);
};
```

But, when I want to cut from the left to an input it doesn't work does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event handlers, or else they will not execute on event firing.

Example:

```
$(function (){
    $('#add').click(ajouteritems);
    $('#delete').click(enleveritems);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2uZ7/1/

Comment: here is what i did with what you told me : var lesoptions = $('#droite').find(":selected");
lesoptions.remove().appendTo($('#choose'));                             but it's not working do you see why ??

Comment: My apologies, seems like append() and appendTo() will do the same thing. However I tried to bind your event handles to your buttons and it seems to work. Please see the update.